# Casting Dictionaries in C#

Tags: c#, reflection, casting

I have the following property declared in my C# class, that we'll call MyMainClass:

```
    private Dictionary<int, Dictionary<int, Dictionary<int, MyOtherClass>>> _oMyObjByTypeIDPeriodIDStatusID = null;
    public Dictionary<int, Dictionary<int, Dictionary<int, MyOtherClass>>> oMyObjByTypeIDPeriodIDStatusID
    {
        get
        {
            return _oMyObjByTypeIDPeriodIDStatusID;
        }
        set
        {
            _oMyObjByTypeIDPeriodIDStatusID = value;
        }
    }
```

Sometimes, through reflection I'll run something like:

```
    string propName = "oMyObjByTypeIDPeriodIDStatusID[2][4[6]";
    object o = GetReflectedProperty(oMyMainClass, propName);
```

But that won't work because of the indexing, so instead I'll strip out the indexes and throw them in an int array.  Then I run

```
    int idxs = new int[] {2,4,6};
    string propName = "oMyObjByTypeIDPeriodIDStatusID";
    object o = GetReflectedProperty(oMyMainClass, propName);
```

That works, but now I have an object, whose value is of type

```
    Dictionary<int, Dictionary<int, Dictionary<int, MyOtherClass>>>
```

And now I somehow have to traverse through each index until I finally get to the last nested Dictionary and the instance of MyOtherClass.  I tried the following code:

```
    for (int i = 0; i < idxs.Length; i++)
        o = ((Dictionary<int, object>)o)[idxs[i]];
```

But that throws an error that it can't cast

```
    Dictionary<int, Dictionary<int, Dictionary<int, MyOtherClass>>>
```

into

```
    Dictionary<int, object>
```

which makes sense.  My problem is, this code is generic, so I don't know what type it will be.  In other words, I use it for different properties, so I don't know how many nested dictionaries there will be, so how can I cast it properly?

Comment: What is `GetReflectedProperty`? Why don't you change that to handle indexes inside a dictionary?

Comment: If I didn't get an answer to this question, I was planning to post another one asking how I can modify GetReflectedProperty to do just that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you break apart going through the layers to two steps, one to go through the nested dictionaries and one to get the final value you can use the non-generic interface [`IDictonary`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.Collections.IDictionary%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) and change your `for` loop to

```
for (int i = 0; i < idxs.Length - 1; i++)
    o = ((IDictionary)o)[idxs[i]];

o = ((IDictionary)o)[idxs[idxs.Length - 1]];
```

and that should fix your casting errors.

Comment: Thanks.  It wants me to provide "2 type arguments" to IDictionary though.  Won't compile without it.

Comment: You need to include `using System.Collections;` at the top of your file to get `IDictionary` to work. Your compiler is attempting to use [`IDictionary<TKey, TValue>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s4ys34ea(v=vs.110).aspx) which is a totally different interface under `System.Collections.Generic` which you likely have by default at the top of the file already.

Answer (score 2):

You could just cast it to an [`IDictionary`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.idictionary.item%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), if you don't know the generic type parameters at compile-time.

Just like `Dictionary<TKey, TValue>`, `IDictionary` has an [indexer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.Collections.IDictionary%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), so you should be able to iterate through the inner dictionaries using that interface.

Comment: It wants me to specify TKey and TValue for IDictionary unfortunately.

Comment: Include system.collections

Answer (score 1):

The real issue here is that Dictionary<TKey,TValue> is strongly typed, so the system doesn't recognize it as Dictionary<int,object> *even though* TValue is derived from object. Try this instead (using Linq):

```
var recastDictionary = o
    .Select(x => new { Key = x.Key, Value = (object)x})
    .ToDictionary(x => x.Key, x => x.Value)
;
```

That should recast the values and give you a Dictionary<int,object> without any hassle or loss of data. (I'm sure there's more efficient ways to do it, but that should be acceptable enough, or at least give you an idea of what you need to do.)

Comment: I really where you're going with this, and I was kind of hoping there would be a linq solution, but o is of type object though.  It's value is a Dictionary, but it's declared as object o.  So, I don't have access to .Select.  Ideas around that?

Comment: Doh. I had an answer prepared, but I forget KeyValuePair was a generic. You may want to try (o as IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<int,object>>), but at that point, you're probably better off going with the answer you checked.